# Grails Fields Plugin using field templates issue

Tags: templates, grails, plugins, field

unfortunatly I can't find any good example where use of the Grails fields plugin is made.
WIthin my app I would like to have some field rendered as a different type like text area or later the CKE editor. My domain:

```
class Case {    
    String description
}
```

I've created a _input.gsp that is found by the plugin:
INFO  formfields.FormFieldsTemplateService  - found template /patchCase/description/input

It contains:

```
<f:field  bean="Case" property="description">
  <g:textArea name="description" cols="40" rows="5" maxlength="5000" value="some default text"/>
</f:field>
```

However I get

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NotReadablePropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /M3PatchManage/patchCase/create
Invalid property 'description' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'description' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error executing tag <f:all>: Error executing tag <f:field>: Invalid property 'description' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Bean property 'description' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Can any one describe how to use the customisation of fields or give a link with a good description (plugin doc is very thin)?

I'm on Grails 2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is the `bean="Case"` attribute. It seems the fields plugin is trying to render properties of the String `"Case"` rather than an instance of the `Case` class.

You should instead pass either the model key name of a `Case` instance, or the instance itself to this attribute. I would guess either of the following might work: `bean="case"` or `bean="${case}"`.

Here's [a Grails app of mine](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals) that makes extensive use of the fields plugin. Some example fields plugin templates are [here](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals/tree/master/grails-app/views/_fields) and here's [a form](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals/blob/master/grails-app/views/competition/_form.gsp) that uses them.

You'll notice that in almost all cases, an input field is passed as the body of the `f:field` tag, e.g.

```
<f:field bean="competition" property="code" label="Code">
  <g:textField name="${property}" value="${value}" class="input-xlarge" maxlength="191"/>
</f:field>
```

This could be expressed more concisely as:

```
<f:field bean="competition" property="code" label="Code" 
        input-class="input-xlarge" input-maxlength="191"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Having <g:textArea name="${property}" value="${value}" class="input-xlarge" maxlength="5000"/> in _input.gsp works now!

Comment: As I explained above, you should try to avoid adding markup for the input field to the body of `<f:field>`

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same issue. Try to use bean="${class}" instead of bean="class".
On "class" put the name of the class that you are trying to bean